# wso2 am: cannot import APIs from 1.9.0 or 1.10.0 to 1.10.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I exported an API package(in .zip format) from wso2 am 1.9.0, later I used this package to import the API to a wso2 1.10.0 installation. It failed with the following error messages, notably "**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getCurrentContext()Lorg/wso2/carbon/context/CarbonContext;**":

```
==> .../repository/logs/wso2-apigw-errors.log <==
```

2016-07-12 04:51:59,823 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-44] ERROR AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver Error occurred during error handling, give up!

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getCurrentContext()Lorg/wso2/carbon/context/CarbonContext;

at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:170)
...

at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
...

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)

at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getCurrentContext()Lorg/wso2/carbon/context/CarbonContext;**

at apim.restful.importexport.utils.AuthenticatorUtil.authorizeUser(AuthenticatorUtil.java:88)

at apim.restful.importexport.APIService.importAPI(APIService.java:171)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)

at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)

... 43 more

I am using api-import-export-v0.9.1 to import/export APIs from wso2 am 1.9.0 to 1.10.0.

What is wrong here? Why "**NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getCurrentContext()**"? Did I use the right import/export tool/version? Any WIKI/documentations about it other than the one in WSO2 web site? Thanks for any tips in advance.

Did anyone get API import working? I also exported APIs from wso2 am 1.10.0 and import to the same 1.10.0 am server, it failed with the same "***java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.wso2.carbon.context.CarbonContext.getCurrentContext()Lorg/wso2/carbon/context/CarbonContext***".

Answer (score 0):

We use this tool with [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud/) successfully. You can refer the doc in Cloud documentation.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Migrate+your+APIs+between+Environments

AFAIK, this tool cannot be used to import export APIs between two different versions of WSO2 API Manager. I didn't see this mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment) though. i.e. If you export from 1.9.1, you cannot import it to 1.10.0. I think the reasons are the api changes etc.

I looked for some evidence showing the version incompatibility thing. But, I couldn't find any.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Actually I also followed the instructions here at https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Migrate+your+APIs+between+Environments . Too bad WSO2 docs do not mention the incompatibility, too bad you cannot migrate APIs from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0, thinking if you have hundreds of thousands of APIs in production! This is really an unacceptable practice for an enterprise application. Maybe the solution is hidden somewhere in their "premium" support, but this tactic might kill this open-source project - folks evaluating WSO2 will think twice before they choose WSO2.

Comment: Intention of the import/export tool is to migrate apis across different environments. i.e. from your dev to test, test to prod, etc. Therefore, it expects the same version to be used in the exported and imported environments.
I have checked this with the team. They will update the document. In the meantime, they are working on supporting import/export across different versions too. Open source code evolves with feedback. We cannot expect the ultimate solution in the first go :)

Comment: Also, at the moment, answer for migrating across different versions is the migration tool/component. I have seen you have raised some concerns about it too. But, the truth is, there is nothing hidden in the commercial support. WSO2 doesn't have free and commercial versions. Everything is included in the freely available distributions.

Comment: Thanks for the update Amila. Is there a doc that clearly describes steps how to migrate APIs from 1.9.0 to 1.10.0, ***backed up by real tests and really works? Current wso2 am 1.10.0 migration steps cannot migrate APIs from 1.9.0. I followed instructions and it did not. My take is, you have to have a migration path to migrate data when users upgrade. Please make this one of the top priorities. No one will use a product that will not migrate data after upgrade, especially for enterprise applications

Comment: Official document which I know for upgrade is https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Upgrading+from+the+Previous+Release. I believe your deployment is a single node one. If so, from my experience, upgrade shouldn't be hard. One important thing to note is, its better you have a duplicate of your deployment and you try the upgrade in that environment. Its very difficult to help on this topic via stackoverflow unfortunately. I know the upgrade works because I did it with my team for http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud

Comment: Thanks Amila. I followed that doc, I upgraded from 190 to 1100, but the APIs were not migrated... The old APIs showed up in carbon ui, but NOT in publisher or storefront. My question is, were you able to migrate APIs as well from 190 to 1100 so that you can see old APIs show up in publisher and store UIS correctly?

Comment: Yes. For me it worked. I think the migration has worked for you. Thats why the apis appear in the carbon ui. Publisher and store gets api related metadata from the registry (which is a database). So, you need to pint your 1.10 instance to the same databses which you use for 1.9.